# OpenCV VideoWriter speed goes up as outside becoming darker

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple `opencv` program to save a video from my `USB` camera. Camera has few supported resolutions

```
1600x1200 <= 5fps
1280x720 <= 11.120fps
800x600 <= 20fps
640x480 <= 30fps
```

I'm using it this way: (It's just a strip from my code)

```py
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS

cam.set(3, width)
cam.set(4, height)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")

out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, fps, (width, height))
while cam.isOpened():
    img = cam.read()[1]
    out.write(main_img)

# etc....
```

This is saving my video as `1600x1200 5fps` in daytime and also in night with real time speed.

But when I do something like this

```py
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = 1280
height = 720
fps = 11.120

# ....
```

I'm getting video `1280x720 11.120fps` in daytime and also in night, but in night my video getting faster! Like fast-forwarding, 1 sec takes 0.5 sec and everything in the video is moving faster.

How could I avoid this? Is it because my camera is too sh*tty and can't get faster shutter speed at night so `cv2` to persist`11.120 fps` fast-forwarding the video?

Comment: your camera must have some low light compensation which simply reduces the frame rate, to get longer exposure times. that causes fewer frames to be produced, which appears as if the video speeds up. investigate the camera's settings.

Comment: if you cant change the camera behaviour you can measure the actual dynamic fps (by generating and evaluating timestamps in your program) and insert dummy frames (duplicates of previous frames) when needed.